# How we can change "This role reports to" lookup value for partner executive role in role hierarchy

Tags: role-hierarchy

I want to change "This role reports to" lookup value for "Partner Executive" role in role hierarchy by default Partner Executive role report to General Profile role in role hierarchy.

Current Role Hierarchy:
Exicom » Managing Director » General Profile » EXICOM Partner Executive » EXICOM Partner Manager » EXICOM Partner User

Required Role Hierarchy:
Hierarchy: Exicom » Managing Director » General Profile » GM O&M Head » Marketing » Finance » Inventory Head » Read Only » Call Center » Commercial Executive » Battery User » Battery Team » EXICOM Partner Executive » EXICOM Partner Manager » EXICOM Partner User